# How to masking input for money with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I've been struggling with a mask in jquery and would like to know if its possible to place a mask with 2 decimals as mandatory.

Example:
I have the following mask:

```
$('.money2').mask("###.###.###.##0,00 €", {reverse: true });
```

When I start placing `5` on an input it shows as `5 €`, what I would like is to show `5,00 €` or `0,05 €`.
I've tried doing it on change but it seems it misses to point of having the mask.

Comment: have you try this [input mask plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: Yes I did try but had the same results